# nhibernate-core does not contain Remotion.Linq namespace

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

the latest NHibernate.dll from Nuget contains the Remotion.Linq namespace(s), but the [nhibernate-core from github](https://github.com/nhibernate) does not do so. Is there a NHibernate source code repository in the public domain that contains Remotion.Linq and its implementation?

Thank you.

Comment: Did my answer below solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

NHibernate embeds the compiled Remotion.Linq. But Remotion.Linq is a separate project with their own project pages: https://relinq.codeplex.com/